# How does a GitHub repository have zero contributors with obvious commits?

Tags: github

I noticed that a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/atomiks/reddit-user-analyser) has zero contributors with obvious commits. How is this possible?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2byJ.png]

Comment: Can you link that repository?

Comment: Updated the question with the repository.

Comment: seems like question more appropriate for GitHub support, than for SO

Comment: @EvgenyVeretennikov I tried looking for a GitHub FAQ that has this information but couldn't find one. I think adding this knowledge to SO's knowledge base could be useful for others too. Instead of waiting for a reply from GitHub support, they can find the answer immediately through a search that refers to this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The committer email is not associated with *any* GitHub account. By picking a random commit, add adding the `.patch` suffix you can see this:

> https://github.com/atomiks/reddit-user-analyser/commit/508b9f745dcfd9117367fa88e982bb739ecac616.patch

```
From 508b9f745dcfd9117367fa88e982bb739ecac616 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: atomiks <na@gmail.com>
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 08:47:53 +1100
Subject: [PATCH] separate comments and submissions timeframes

...
```

The `na@gmail.com` is probably not associated with any GitHub account.

---

You can create such a repository following these steps:

```
# Create the Git repo locally
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /.../foo/.git/

# Create some files
$ echo 'foo' > index.js
$ ls
index.js

# Create the commit, but pass an invalid email address
# or one you are sure that is not associated with *any*
# GitHub account
$ git add . -A
$ git commit -m 'Initial' . --author 'foo <fooooooo_or_invalid_email_address_which_is_not_on_github@bar.com>'
[master a34597b] Initial
 Author: foo <fooooooo_or_invalid_email_address_which_is_not_on_github@bar.com>
 Date: Wed May 31 13:51:19 2017 +0300
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 index.js

# Add the GitHub url
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:IonicaBizau/tmp42.git

# Push the repo
$ git push --all
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 271 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:IonicaBizau/tmp42.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Then on the Github repo page you will see:

[image]

Clicking on the commit url and adding the `.patch` suffix (to get the raw information):

```
From a34597b39da17eb77ab29f686a78b276a3c18376 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: foo <fooooooo_or_invalid_email_address_which_is_not_on_github@bar.com>
Date: Wed, 31 May 2017 13:51:19 +0300
Subject: [PATCH] Initial

---
 index.js | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 index.js

diff --git a/index.js b/index.js
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..257cc56
--- /dev/null
+++ b/index.js
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+foo
```

Comment: @mythereal I just added an example. You can change the author of the commit by using the `--author` option or by editing the `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. That was enlightening.